# Calling another function with same params but different name with Generics throws an error in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to call someMethodB from someMethodA and getting the following compile error `Cannot convert the expression's type '$T2[]' to type 'T[]'`

```
func someMethodA<T : Equatable>(array: T[], values: T...) -> T[] {
    return self.someMethodB(array, values: values)
}

func someMethodB<T : Equatable>(array: T[], values: T...) -> T[] {
    ...
}
```

Seems like a problem due to variadic parameter. How can I pass values which is converted to an array as variadic to someMethodB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MethodB takes a variadic second parameter, but you are sending it an array. You can change your method signature of MethodB to this:

```
someMethodB<T : Equatable>(array: T[], values: T[]) -> T[]{ /* code */ }
```

When you pass a variadic parameter into a method it gets converted into an array. So values is actually a `T[]` and not a `T...`

Edit: If you still need a someMethodB that takes a variadic parameter you can just have it call the one that takes the array like this:

```
func someMethodB<T : Equatable>(array: T[], values: T...) -> T[] {
    return someMethodB(array, values:values)
}
```

Comment: So then my question is how can I pass variadic parameter using an array T[]?

Comment: You can't convert an array into a variadic parameter. You can make 2 MethodB's though. One that takes a variadic parameter and one that takes an array. The one that takes the variadic parameter can just call the one that takes the array

Comment: OK so create an overloaded parameter. Thanks!